Minka Aire remote appears to be ON all the time with no change to the fan function
The green light on the remote is always on when the battery is in place. The fan does not respond to any pressed buttons. Occasionally, it seems to make a connection and will perform all the past requested functions very quickly - like changing direction 3, 4 times, changing speeds. It is now off and it will not respond to the remote request for start again.
The fan is hardwired and has no on/off switch.
I have tried to reset the remote by flipping the breaker off/on then pressing the center button of the remote (on/off button) for 3 seconds to reset it. But the green light is on all the time so the reset function does not have any effect.
I assume the issue is at the fan itself. What needs to be assessed at that location?

Was the green light always on before(since new)?  Have you replace the battery with a new one?

It sounds to me like one of the remote buttons is stuck in the "pushed' position.   I'm an electrician and have never seen a Minka fan remote where the green light stays on,  as it should only blink green when a button is pressed.  The other buttons aren't working because of the stuck button,  you either need a replacement remote or to try getting the button unstuck.  It may be hard to tell which one is stuck.  I would flip it over and tap on it with something with a little force to fix it.

Hi Bryan, I  find this very hard to read. You have punctuations which is great. Would please edit and insert spaces after them? This would make the answer easier to read.

I'm sorry, it must look different to someone reading my comment compared to how I see it, I went back and spaced after each period and comma.

You may have frequency interference.
Try this procedure from Minka Aire's manual:
SYMPTOM
Frequency Interference
Turn the power off to your ceiling fan.
Please use a small size tool to change the frequency settings on the control system.
Return power to the unit.
Note: After the AC power is on, do not press any other button on the transmitter before pressing the "Stop" button, doing so will cause the
procedure to fail.
Within 60 seconds of turning the Fan's AC power ON. Press the transmitter's "Stop" button and hold the "Stop¡" button for 10 seconds.
Once the receiver has detected the set frequency, the down light of your fan if applicable will blink twice. (there is no indication if your fan is not
equipped with a light).
The receiver has now learn the frequency which has been selected on the transmitter. After completing the steps above, you should be able to
operate the ceiling fan and light. If the fan is not responding to the transmitter, please turn the power off to the receiver, and repeat the process
